# Place Custom Checkbox Icon to right of label Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, checkbox, bootstrap-4

I have tried everything but I can't place checkbox right to the label. I could move the checkbox to the right of label, if it is general type of checkbox. But I could not do the same with custom-checkbox type.

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck" name="example1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">Label</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The custom checkbox is created with pseudo elements so their positioning needs to be adjusted relative to the label.

```css
.custom-control.custom-checkbox{padding-left: 0;}

label.custom-control-label {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
}

label.custom-control-label::before, label.custom-control-label::after{
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck" name="example1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">Label</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

The earlier @serg-chernata answer doesn't seem to work for me with `custom-switch`. Here's an example i got working.

**CSS**

```
div.custom-control-right {
    padding-right: 24px;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
div.custom-control-right .custom-control-label::after{
    right: -1.5rem;
    left: auto;
}
div.custom-control-right .custom-control-label::before {
    right: -2.35rem;
    left: auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="custom-control custom-control-right custom-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" disabled id="customSwitch2">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch2">Right switch element</label>
</div>
```

**JsFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/2cmbq9r0/

**Screenshot**

[image: Toggle switches left and right]

*Edit: changed `left:initial` to `left:auto` to make it work with IE11.*

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with...

1. Greater distance between the label and checkbox
2. Using the basic `form-check` class instead of `custom-control`

then one alternative is using a `col-right` class to move the checkbox to the far side of your form. In some cases, I have found that aligning labels and input elements on the far-left and far-right, respectively, provides a nice consistent look

```
<div class="row form-row">
  <div class="col">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="customCheck">Label</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-right">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="customCheck" name="example1">
  </div>
</div>
```