# Bootstrap 4 checkbox not appearing when trying to set it to the rightside of the label

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get the checkbox to be displayed on the right side of the label. The code I have in the snippet shows the checkbox appearing on the right side, but when I apply that same code to my project, the checkbox doesn't appear in my browser and the label, which in this case is 390.00, gets highlighted. I provided a picture below to show you what I mean. Does anyone know what the issue could be? This is grabbing the checkbox element from Bootstrap.

[image]

```css
"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="radio1" id="radio1">
<label for="acme">390.00</label>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="390.00" name="acme_bill" id="acme" onclick="updateTotal()">
                                
                            </div>
```

Comment: Try to wrap your label elements around the input element. Place </label> after input.

Comment: No luck, I also tried that. Might have to see how I have my bootstrap.css set up

Comment: Can you provide all the code for your table? Will that recreate your problem in the code snippet tool?

Comment: Have nice solution for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52366400/place-custom-checkbox-icon-to-right-of-label-bootstrap-4/52375015